# Android managging monitors concurrency with buttons

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, concurrency

## Context

I need to manage the concurrency of an app. I declared a `Object sync` to use monitors on that object.

The main goal is that the first button, `A`, will execute some code, but, when reaching some points, it needs button `B` to be clicked to be able to continue. Something like this:

[image: Flow demo]

## Issues

The issue is that the `B` button can't be clicked, I guess it's because the UI thread is stuck waiting for the code of button `A` to be fully executed before raising other button events.

If I execute the code in button `A` in a new `Thread`, when I try to update the `View` (called *UI* in the drawing), I get `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

## Edit

I solved it adding a `Handler` for the UI update and the already added `Thread` for the code in `A`.

Answer (score -1):

Factor the code that is taking the time into a Runnable that you execute in a separate thread, but once you've started that thread, do the UI update in the original thread.

Comment: Could you explain this more in detail?

Comment: Why don't you do the best you can incorporating that into  your own code?  Most likely you'll understand if you do it.  If not, add your code  to the answer and maybe I can provide more input.

Comment: Do you name this an answer? Those 2 lines? You were supposed to explain your *answer*. You wrote 4 lines (20 seconds) with 0 meaning, 0 constructive and 0 informative, instead of mentioning Handlers, AsyncTask etc. If I knew how to update the UI from another thread, I would have not asked it here. This is how you got your 5k rep ?

Comment: If what you want is someone to write your code for you, you've come to the wrong site.

Comment: In my question I asked for ideas. In my first comment I asked for an explanation. In my second comment I said you should have mentioned solutions like Handlers. In my edit I added the concept for the solution. No one mentioned code here, only you did Don't make up things. Better erase your *answer*.

Comment: The next step in detail is either coding, or looking up the Javadoc on things like `Thread` and `Runnable`.  Neither are things you should expect someone else to do for you.  You are the one looking for help; you should expect to do most of the work.

Comment: First, I solved it. Second, I am already familiar with those concepts. Third, I did most of the work since I already solved it. I don't even know what all this comes from ... Looks like communicating is not one of your strenghts. Feels like talking to clever bot. Totally random answers.